# Eclipse Marketplace option not available in Help menu

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-ide

Eclipse Marketplace option not available in Help menu.

If link is available to install Marketplace client in STS 3.8.4 would be useful,

so that i can install marketplace via Install new software.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Spring Dashboard, go to IDE Extensions and install Spring IDE(Tool support for the Spring Framework), restart the IDE and the option will appear. That works for me in STS 3.8.4

Comment: Already that extension installed, but not able to view. same version of STS im using 3.8.4

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to install market place as new software.
https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/installnewsoftware.html

URL for market place install is : http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-12

2019-12 represent eclipse version you are using for me it was 2020-06 {version :4.16}
hence URL for me changed to  http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-06
then restart the IDE.
search for Spring ide in market place after reopening it will show version 3 tool.